# change the foreign key field from select box to raw_id_fields in my custom form

Tags: python, django, forms, foreign-keys

i m not working with the admin.py 
is there any way i could have the foreign key field instead of a drop down select box , a dynamic search box(suggestive for the user) like we have raw_id_fields in admin.py.

models.py

```
class model2(models.Model)
     reg = models.ForeignKey(model1, db_column='reg')
     class Meta:
         db_table = u'table2'
```

forms.py

```
class model2Form(ModelFOrm)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(model2Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
        if instance and instance.id:
            self.fields['reg'].required = False
            self.fields['reg'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = 'disabled'
    def clean_regid(self):
        if self.instance and self.instance.pk:
            return self.instance.reg
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data['reg']
    class Meta:
        model = model2
        exclude = ('id')
```

views.py

```
def add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = model2Form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           return list(request) 
        else :
            raise RuntimeError('Form is invalid')
    else :
        action = model2().get_add_url()
        form = model2Form()
        c = {'form': form, 'action' : action}
        c.update(csrf(request))
        return render_to_response('add.html', c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily have [autocomplete](http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/auto-complete).

Comment: There is a lot of [manual](http://django-autocomplete-light.rtfd.org) and [examples](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/tree/master/test_project) for django-autocomplete-light. There is even more, it's all in the [README](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/blob/master/README). [Russian documentation](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/blob/master/README_RUS.rst) was also contributed. But you've probably found all this since you asked :) I'll upload a new video today i'll let you know when it's online it might help.